# Yii2 не работает валидация по сценариям

Tags: php, yii2, валидация

Есть вот такая вот форма для добавления
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В модель добавил  следующие поля:

```
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';
public $scenario;
```

Метод валидации в модели:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        ['name', 'string'],
        ['price', 'integer'],
        [['name', 'price','tags'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CREATE],
    ];
}
```

"Переопределение" сценариев, не знаю зачем это, но во всех статьях советуют:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios['create'] = ['name', 'price', 'tags'];
    return $scenarios;
}
```

В контроллере перед заполнением модели создаю ее подобным образом:

```
$model = new Product(['scenario' => Product::SCENARIO_CREATE]);
```

Как итог - со сценариями нечего не работает, работает, только если убрать из метода с валидацией привязку сценария

Comment: "*"Переопределение" сценариев, не знаю зачем это, но во всех статьях советуют:*" --- наверное это если совсем совсем кастомное опеределение..... я никогда так не делаю и работает)   только в search моделях написано `public function scenarios() { return Model::scenarios();  }`  и то не уверен что оно нужно))

Comment: Попробуй вместо  `$model = new Product(['scenario' => Product::SCENARIO_CREATE]);`  написать так `$model = new Product(); $model->scenario = Product::SCENARIO_CREATE;`  а  в методе `scenarios`  оставить только вызов родительского сценария

Comment: Попробовал, не работает

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение через вот такую вот штуку:

```
$model->setScenario(Product::SCENARIO_CREATE);
```